# Как в WordPress узнать, на какой странице находится пользователь?

Tags: wordpress

Какая функция в WordPress выводит, на каком типе страницы находится пользователь (рубрики, главная страница, пост)?

Не знаю, как найти в Google, поэтому обращаюсь к вам, спасибо.

Comment: Почитайте здесь: http://wp-kama.ru/id_89/uslovnyie-tegi-v-wordpress-i-vse-chto-s-nimi-svyazano.html Функции `is_home`, `is_single` и так далее.

Answer (score 1):

Следующая функция возвращает тип записи по идентификатору поста.

```
$type = get_post_type( $post_id );
echo $type;
```

Функция возвращает тип вида attachment, post  и т.п.
Внутри цикла WordPress можно сделать проще

```
$type = $the_post->post_type;
echo $type;
```

Если отображается страница (page), то можно проверить, это главная страница или нет:

```
if( is_front_page() ) {
  // сделать что-то
}
```